# Does web server normalize path passed by browser client?

Tags: php, web-services, http

I am reviewing some php code and a question came to my head - does web server normalize the path sent by the client.

For example, if a client enters http://example.code/tut/../123.html URL. What the server will get from _SERVER['HTTP_URI'] varable? 123.html or tut/../123.html?

Comment: Have you *tried* or are you just asking?

Comment: +1 for Tomalak. This would've taken less time to try out than it did to post on SO about.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `$_SERVER['HTTP_URI']` variable. There's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and it will provide `/tut/../123.html`.